# displaying dt tag side by side instead of one below another

Tags: html, css

I want to display `dt` of HTML tag side by side instead of one below another
For example:--

```
<dl class='Desktop'>
  <dt class='first'>first</dt>
  <dt class='Second'>second</dt>
  <dt class='third'>third</dt>
</dl>
```

Output: `first` `second` `third`

Answer (score 1):

I like all the other answers as they are good, but I think mine is a lot simpler and doesn't require IE hacks:

```
dt {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution, if you don't have to set the width of the `dt`s. This only works with `block` or `inline-block`...

Comment: @Dave, agree, but the OP never mentioned that he/she wants to set the width of element, they only need to be side by side. Obviously if the width becomes a requirement then `inline-block` would be the next best choice.

Comment: this wasn't meant as criticism, rather a hint for the OP to pick your answer :-) It's actually the simplest solution, and if it works, why do it more complicated?...

Comment: @Dave, I apologise, I misunderstood. Thanks for your support to my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
dl.Desktop dt{float:left;}
```

Will get them side by side. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/zD8bs/.

Note: there may be additional styling needed to get it just right.

Comment: also width is factor to consider

Answer (score 0):

You can either make them float left:

```
dt {
    float: left;
}
```

Or make them inline-block:

```
dt {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1; /* IE hack */
    *display: inline; /* IE hack */
}
```

[Why inline-block may be desirable](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/).